# Axios formData with image is sending empty array

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have a put method to my profile route in the backend, I need a token authentication so in order to be authorized I have to pass the token through a header, I get an error because for some reason it's sending an empty formData when I log the request in my backend.

I tested the backend with postman and everything works as intended so it's not a backend issue, it's totally something wrong in the request I'm doing from the frontend, but I don't know how to handle this, any clue?

```
profile_update() {
            let params = {
                email: this.profile.email,
                password: this.profile.password,
                coin: this.profile.coin,
                phone_country: this.profile.phone_country,
                phone_area: this.profile.area_code,
                phone_number: this.profile.number,
                first_name: this.profile.first_name,
                last_name: this.profile.last_name,
                date_of_birth: this.profile.date_of_birth,
                gender: this.profile.gender,
                city_id: this.profile.city,
                wants_to_change_password: this.profile.wants_to_change_password,
                state_id: this.profile.state,
                city_id: this.profile.city
            }

            let headers = {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer' + this.token
            }

            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('profile-picture', this.profile.profile_picture)
            formData.append('data', params)
            formData.append('headers', headers)
            formData.append('_method', 'PUT')

            axios.put(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/profile`, formData, headers).then(res => {
                console.log(res)
            }).catch(e => {
                console.log(e)
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
axios.put(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/profile`, {'profile-picture':this.profile.profile_picture}, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.token,
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
}).then(res => {
     console.log(res)
}).catch(e => {
     console.log(e)
})
```

Hope this may solve your problem. For more info read [docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#axios-api)

Comment: it still sends an empty array

Comment: Try adding content type property in header. I have edited the answer do check

Comment: it's still empty

Comment: so, i tried to add an extra parameter with a random value, by removing the content-type: multipart/form-data it sends the parameter but sends the image as an empty array, i need to send the image and seems that i can't use formdata for that, not sure if it's an axios issue or server issue though

Comment: nevermind, i had to do a post request appending `formData.append('method', '_PUT')` i totally forgot about that, i was making a put request directly